# Problem with executing statement returned from an UDF - no result set

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have made a User-Defined Function that returns a WHERE statement based on some values in another table.

```
WHERE dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.accountID = 1210
```

Then I use a stored procedure to construct and execute the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.*, dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.description As header
FROM dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.tblJournalAccountHead ON dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.documentReference = dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.documentReference
WHERE dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.accountID = 1210
```

Everything runs successfully but I am getting empty results. When I just execute the statement without using the function I will get results, so I know that is not the problem.

Stored procedure `(@reportID = 10000)`

```
DECLARE @sql_select nvarchar(1000)

IF (@reportID = 10000) BEGIN 
    SET @sql_select = 
        'SELECT dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.*, dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.description As header ' +
        'FROM dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry ' + 
        'INNER JOIN dbo.tblJournalAccountHead ON dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.documentReference = dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.documentReference '
END

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000) = @sql_select + dbo.reportWhere(@reportID)

EXEC ( @sql )
```

Using MS-SQL with Access 2010 in an ADP.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The reason it was not working is apperantly is because it is not supposed to:

*Dynamic SQL in User-Defined Functions*

*This very simple: you cannot use dynamic SQL from used-defined functions written in T-SQL. This is because you are not permitted do anything in a UDF that could change the database state (as the UDF may be invoked as part of a query). Since you can do anything from dynamic SQL, including updates, it is obvious why dynamic SQL is not permitted.*

*[Source:The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)*

Answer (score 1):

Stefan;

I think that you have that backwards.  UDF are allowed in dynamic-SQL.  Dynamic-SQL is not allowed in UDFs.

For example

DECLARE @sql_select nvarchar(1000)

IF (@reportID = 10000) BEGIN 
    SELECT @sql_select = 
        'SELECT dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.*, dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.description As header ' +
        'FROM dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry ' + 
        'INNER JOIN dbo.tblJournalAccountHead ON dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.documentReference = dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.documentReference ' + dbo.reportWhere(@reportID)
END

EXEC ( @sql )

-Aaron
MCITP: DBA

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand in your question, where the stored procedure, where the function, how they are supposed to be. I think there is enough of a function that returns a table value, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_MyFunc(@AccountID int)
returns @Result Table(field1 f1type, ..., Header varchar(50))
as
BEGIN

Insert into @Result(field1 f1type, ..., Header varchar(50))
SELECT dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.*, dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.description As header
FROM dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry
INNER JOIN dbo.tblJournalAccountHead ON dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.documentReference = dbo.tblJournalAccountHead.documentReference
WHERE dbo.tblGeneralLedgerEntry.accountID = @AccountID

Return

END
```

Using as:

```
select * from dbo.fn_MyFunc(dbo.reportWhere(@reportID))
```

In this case the UDF dbo.ReportWhere must return an integer scalar value

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I found that UDF are not allowed in dynamic SQL.